# Getting everything from an SQL table and inserting them into a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

So I am getting the elements from the MySQL table and I want to make them into an array and then merge that array which gets encoded into JSON. It doesn't error but it only is displaying an empty JSON string'[]'

```
<?php
include "connectdb.php";
$banned = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banned");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $user = array(
        UserId => $row["userId"],
        Reason => $row["reason"],
    );
    array_merge($banned,$user);
}

echo json_encode($banned);
?>
```

Comment: It seems as though array_merge is not working. Any other functions with the same ability?

Comment: `$banned[] = $row;`. `array_merge` RETURNS the merged array, which you're not capturing and therefore throwing away

Comment: @AndyLester yes. The loop does execute, but as I stated in my comment, it seems to be that array_merge isn't working. I echoed $row["userId"] and $row["reason"] and the correct data came up. It just isn't merging those two arrays together.

Comment: @MarcB oh I see. So I would have to set banned each time I merge?

Comment: no. you don't need to merge at all. just use the `$banned[] = $row` syntax, which is a shortcut for array_push.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to add a $user array, which you're using as sort of an object, to the $banned array.

To push something onto an array, use `array_push`, or this notation:

```
$banned[] = $user;
```

Comment: Then how would I do individual arrays inside of the array. I want to be able to see what user was banned for.

Answer (score 0):

Your php looks fine, so we are doen to your database or query. Put this line after your query:

```
echo mysql_num_rows($query);
```

See if this number is 0. If it is, you are not actually getting any information back from your query.

If that doesn't help locate the problem, keep using echo liberally, at ever line if you need to. See what is happening and why. This is the way you diagnose a problem. Echo the $row["userId"], echo the $banned variable before encoding, although that will take a var_dump(). Echo everything and you'll locate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First build a multi dimensional array, and encode it for JSON.

```
<?php
include "connectdb.php";
$banned = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banned");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $user = array(
        UserId => $row["userId"],
        Reason => $row["reason"],
    );
    $banned[] = $user;
}

echo json_encode($banned);
?>
```

Then if you need to, you can still access the array like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($banned); $i++) {
    $UserID = $banned[$i]['UserID'];
    $Reason = $banned[$i]['Reason'];
    //Do something with this data like:
    echo "User ".$UserID." was banned for ".$Reason;
}
```